# Site Collections or Subsites with SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Which is better Site Collections or Subsites?

I proposed to structure:
- all teams under the /teams site collection managed path, so 1 site collection per team
- all project/collaboration sites under the /sites managed path, so 1 site collection per project site

I've been overruled by my team who want just two site collections and subsites to hold all the team sites and site collections.

My main reason is keeping the security groups clean and not cluttered. Also keeps things nice and simple.

Downside I can see is branding changes will be difficult across many site collections but I'm sure there's a powershell script which can do this sort of stuff.

Remember: This is SharePoint Online not on premise.

Comment: Please help me understand something, why are you using site collections for every team ? What's the purpose ?

Comment: my thinking is that the security will be easier to manage and keeps things very tidy. Simpler groups makes things less likely to go wrong.if you go subsite route, you'll end up with a very long list of groups. The URL is shorter too.

so say we have multiple teams like team1, team2, team3

https://xyx.sharepoint.com/teams/team1
https://xyx.sharepoint.com/teams/team3
https://xyx.sharepoint.com/teams/team3

whereas the team members propose
https://xyx.sharepoint.com/sites/teams/team1
https://xyx.sharepoint.com/sites/teams/team2
https://xyx.sharepoint.com/sites/teams/team3

Comment: I can see no reason for not doing it the way you suggest especially if security is a concern. There are downsides but as you say you can overcome most of these with Powerhell. It sounds like you are convinced :) I think you need to convince your colleagues. You need to make you arguments clearer but they are sound.

Comment: From a pure security perspective, create a site collection for each team, so each team can manage their own permissions without having permission inheritance headaches in SharePoint between them.

Comment: thanks all, i was outvoted by the rest of the team - someone said you can overcome inheritance issues by not giving the user access to manage permissions but manage groups but then we'll have create groups for the users if they need more.

Comment: Well looks like my model of separation into site collections is being used by SharePoint modern sites.